# Show How to Efficiently Solve the Computational Diffie-Hellman Assumption given an Algorithm that Solves the Square-DH Problem

Tags: diffie-hellman, group-theory

Let $q$ prime number, $G$ a cyclic group with order $q$ and let $g \in G$ be a generator of $G$. Suppose that you have an algorithm $A$ who takes input the element $g^a$ of $G$ and gives as output the element $g^{a^2}$ (i.e., it solves the Square-DH problem). Describe a fast (polynomial time) algorithm who takes as input the elements $g^a$,$g^b$ and gives as output the element $g^{a \cdot b}$ (namely an algorithm that solves the Computational Diffie-Hellman Problem).

Comment: `I tried to solve it but i didn't manage to conclude anywhere.` – To assure we can help you to the best of our abilities… what exactly have you tried, and where exactly did you hit problems?

Comment: It's a difficult problem linked to the "Decisional Diffie Hellman assumption".
Take a look over the web to learn more about this question.

Comment: i am confused on how to construct/find this algorithm

Comment: `i am confused on how to construct/find this algorithm` – Now I am confused if you have a problem “constructing this algorithm” or if you´re having a problem “finding this algorithm”. (To know where you might be taking a wrong path, it would be helpfull to know what you‘ve actually tried.) Anyway… you might want to follow the hint @RobertNACIRI gave you. For example, check related Q&As right here at the Crypto.SE website: [*Decisional Diffie Hellman assumption*](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=Decisional+Diffie+Hellman+assumption).

Comment: cross-posted [from MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1374198/57159) after less than 2 minutes, and answered there $\;$

Comment: Related problem: [Can we reduce Diffie-Hellman problem to “Discrete-log inversion” problem?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26264/can-we-reduce-diffie-hellman-problem-to-discrete-log-inversion-problem)

Answer (score 8):

This is a reduction showing that if you can compute $g^{a^2}$ given $g^a$, then you can solve the computational Diffie Hellman problem. Here is the reduction.

Let $A$ be an adversary that given $g^a$ for a random $a$, outputs $g^{a^2}$ with probability $\epsilon$. We construct $A'$ who receives $u=g^a$ and $v=g^b$ and works as follows. $A'$ runs $A$ three times on input $u$, on input $v$ and on input $u\cdot v$. If $A$ returns a correct answer each time then $A'$ will have $A=g^{a^2}$, $B=g^{b^2}$ and $C=g^{(a+b)^2}=g^{a^2 + 2ab + b^2} = g^{a^2}\cdot g^{b^2} \cdot g^{2ab}$. Thus, $A'$ outputs $\sqrt{\frac{C}{A\cdot B}}$, where the square-root is of course modulo $p$.

It remains to compute the probability with which $A'$ succeeds. Naively, we would like to say that since $A$ has to succeed on all 3 inputs, $A'$ succeeds with probability $\epsilon^3$. The problem is that the inputs given by $A'$ to $A$ are not independent. This is solved by having $A'$ choose random $r$ and $s$ in ${\mathbb Z}_p^*$ and giving $A$ the inputs $g^{ra}=u^r$, $g^{sb}=v^s$ and $u\cdot v$. This will ensure that all inputs are completely independent. Now $A'$ outputs $\sqrt{\frac{C}{A^{1/r^2}\cdot B^{1/s^2}}}$ and this will be correct with probability $\epsilon^3$.

We conclude that if the original problem can be solved with non-negligible probability then so can the computational Diffie-Hellman problem.

Comment: Why the inputs of $A$' are not independent? Can't we choose a random $b$?

Comment: First, note that $A'$ doesn't get to choose $a$ and $b$; it receives $u$ and $v$ and has to work with that. This actually doesn't matter since $a$ and $b$ are independent and random. The problem is that $A'$ runs $A$ on $u$, $v$ and $u\cdot v$. Clearly $u$ and $v$ are independent, but $u\cdot v$ is not independent of $u$ and $v$. This is solved by rerandomizing $u$ and $v$ using $r$ and $s$, but leaving $u\cdot v$ so now all 3 elements are independent.

Comment: I see. A and B changes but not C. That's what I missed while reading. Thanks.