# Weak Decisional Diffie-Hellman Problem

Tags: diffie-hellman, hardness-assumptions

Is this problem still hard?

Given $$(g,g^a,g^b,c)$$ decide if $c=a\cdot b$?

If there is an adversary that solves the standard Decisional Diffie-Hellman Problem then it can solve my new problem. But I can't understand that my new problem still hard or not.

Did anyone see this problem or similar to my problem? Can anyone help me?

Comment: This might help [What is the relation between Discrete Log, Computational Diffie-Hellman and Decisional Diffie-Hellman?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1493/18298)

Comment: @kelaka This doesn't answer the question. Indeed, as the question states - it is clear that if DDH is easy then so is this. However, this is not DL or CDH or DDH since the actual value $c=a\cdot b$ is given, and not $g^c$.

Comment: @YehudaLindell Uh, I read incorrectly,

Comment: Thank you for your answers. But I couldn't find my answer.

Comment: As an aside, I would note that the similar problem "given $(g, g^a, g^b, c)$ is $c = a / b$" turns out to be easy...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is. It can be formally reduced to the hardness of the decisional square Diffie-Hellman assumption, which states that distinguishing $(g,g^a,g^{a^2})$ from random is hard (this is a well established assumption).

It follows in a relatively simple way from the answer I wrote [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/68403/is-it-hard-to-compute-gab-when-given-g-ga-gb-fracab/68419#68419) to a related question. I can let you work out the details in case you want to play a bit with these reductions. In case you cannot figure out the formal reduction, just ask in the comment and I will elaborate.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think that my problem reduced to the decisional inverse Diffie-Hellman assumption, which states that distinguishing $(g,g^a,g^{a^{-1}})$ from random.