On a diffie hellman related oracle
Given an oracle that can compute $g^{x^{-1}}\bmod p$ from $g^x\bmod p$ is it possible to compute $g^{x^2}\bmod p$ in polynomial time ($p$ is a prime and $g$ generates the multiplicative group modulo $p$)?

Most probably yes by intuition. I haven't done serious calc yet.

Already answered in https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26273

Well, if the Oracle works with an arbitrary base 'g', then it is easy.
If we give the Oracle the base $g^x$, and ask it to 'invert' $g$ with respect to that base, that is:
The base is $h = g^x$
The value being inverted is $g = h^{x^{-1}}$
Hence, the Oracle will return the value $h^{{x^{-1}}^{-1}} = h^x = g^{x^2}$
And we're done...

"The value being inverted is g=h^{x^{−1}}".. We are not given h^x.

@Turbo: no, we're not - that's the value that the Oracle gives us...

I don't follow. What is the input to the oracle to get $h^{x^{-1}}$?

@Turbo: the input is $g$; it happens that $g = h^{x^{-1}}$

If the oracle is restricted to working with $g$ as the base, then the reduction is possible by considering the following equality:
$$\frac{1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{x^2 - x}.$$
Inversions in the exponents are implemented by the oracles, while the other operations are done by multiplications/divisions.

This is a better answer than mine...

@poncho, given the lack of specificities in the question, your answer is equally good ;)
